# Is planet.ros.org down?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I access this site, I get a 404 "There isn't a Github pages site here". This has been happening for about a week now.
Is the site gone? If not, what's going on?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342685/is-planet.ros.org-down?/) by [TurtleBot_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/702/turtlebot_fan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2020-01-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2020-01-28**:
I closed this question as it is up now. Hard to tell if it has been down 8 hours ago. If you still experience issues, feel free to reopen, but please add additional details about your setup (system, proxy, ...)
Looking at the latest traffic on the repo, I guess this issue might have been fixed with https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/planet.ros.org/pull/36, though.

In general it is a good idea to check https://status.ros.org/ if anything ROS related is experiencing problems. Though planet.ros.org isn't shown there (opened an issue: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/planet.ros.org/issues/37)...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-28**:
There could have been a problem with that host, but at least right now (ie: 10:23 CET) it's online for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There was an issue https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/planet.ros.org/pull/34 resolved in https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/planet.ros.org/pull/36

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2020-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0